# Bluetooth Chip programming on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to create an application (c/cpp) in AOSP that would allow me to send custom commands to the CSR8510 Bluetooth chip on my Android development board. I was able to find out from the bluedroid source that the function being used to perform such actions is **btu_hcif_send_cmd** and that this function is available in the **bluetooth.default.so** library. I tried linking the bluetooth.default.so library to my application which was using **btu_hcif_send_cmd** and **osi_malloc** functions. The code snippet I used is below.

```
uint8_t controllerID = LOCAL_BR_EDR_CONTROLLER_ID;
size_t cmdSize = HCI_CMD_BUF_SIZE;

cmdPacket = (BT_HDR*)osi_malloc(cmdSize);

cmdPacket->event = 0;
cmdPacket->offset = 0;
cmdPacket->layer_specific = 0;
cmdPacket->len = HCIC_PREAMBLE_SIZE; /*! RESET Command doesn't have any parameters */
cmdStream = cmdPacket->data;

 UINT16_TO_STREAM(cmdStream, HCI_RESET);
 UINT8_TO_STREAM(cmdStream, 0);  /*! RESET Command doesn't have any parameters */     
      btu_hcif_send_cmd(controllerID, cmdPacket);
```

However, I keep getting the following undefined reference errors when trying to compile the application within the AOSP build.

```
error: undefined reference to 'osi_malloc(unsigned int)'
error: undefined reference to 'btu_hcif_send_cmd(unsigned char, BT_HDR*)'
```

Could someone please tell me if I am doing this right and if not, how to do what I want to achieve properly?

Answer (score 0):

Add following line to Android.mk

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libbt-stack libosi
```

However, it is likely that more link error.  Investigating the makefiles in /system/bt will be helpful.

Comment: libbt-stack and libosi are built as static libraries and I've tried adding them and their dependencies as  #LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
  libbt-sbc-decoder \
  libbt-sbc-encoder \
  libFraunhoferAAC \
  libudrv-uipc
  
#LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
  libbt-stack \
  libbtif \
  libbt-bta \
  libbtdevice \
  libbt-hci \
  libbt-protos \
  libbt-utils \
  libbtcore \
  libosi \
  libFraunhoferAAC  That just gave me more linker errors!